# The definition of navbar variable

Tags: moodle-theme

I want to customize a theme from classic theme, it is a child of boost theme. In front page, I want to change the background color and the text color of the Navigation bar. I have changed the background color in

```
<div class="card-body {{^contextheader}}p-2{{/contextheader}}" style="background-color:#026900; padding: .5rem">
   ....
   <\div>
```

of the file full_header.mustache and it works fine.

However, I can't change text color if the Navigation because the color of text is defined in the variable {{{navbar}}} in the template file. If I change the color of class .a then all of text link of the site change.

I don't know and can't find how and where is defined the variable navbar.

Please help me!

Thanks for your help.

Best

[Here is the image of template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEtHm.png)